# Specifying extra information to Mathematica for Simplifying expressions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, constraints, symbolic-math

Sometimes, we know that certain variables are positive, or natural numbers, or real and it helps to simplify the expressions. For example,

```
Integrate[Sign[x], {x, -l/2, l}]
```

evaluates to

```
ConditionalExpression[
 1/2 l (-3 + 6 DiscreteDelta[l] + 2 HeavisideTheta[-l] + 
 4 HeavisideTheta[l]), l \[Element] Reals]
```

But if I know that l is a real positive number, I am actually looking at -l/2. Is there a way to specify this extra information or constraint so Mathematica can simplify the expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will usually evaluate faster if you specify [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Assumptions.html) inside of `Integrate`:

```
Integrate[Sign[x], {x, -l/2, l}, Assumptions -> l > 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer, you can specify assumptions, such as

```
Simplify[Integrate[Sign[x], {x, -l/2, l}], l > 0]
```

which reduces to `l/2`.